# How do I get my server to work through the internet listing?

Tags: steam, garrys-mod

I have set up and port forwarded a DarkRP server, on Garry's Mod. When I go to local game, and select play, it works.

When I search the Internet section for my server, it pops up, but when I select it, it does not work. When other people try to join me through the Internet section, it does not work. When they select my name, and select join, it works.

The IP given on the Internet section is listed as starting with 99. The IP when you select the game through me is listed as starting with 198.

How do I get my server to work from the Internet selection?

Comment: Your ISP may be blocking incoming connections on the specific port.
Try this with the server's port number and see if it's open: http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/

Comment: I have tried cleaning your question up, let me know if i missed anything important.

Comment: It's not the port that is being blocked, I can port forward and everything. It's the IP. The ip on the one that you search starts with 99. But the ip with the one that works is 198.168.65.1. I can connect to the 198 one but when you search the server it comes up with the 99 one, and I can't connect to that one...

Answer (score 1):

By default your server will be running in lan mode which means it doesn't announce itself to the public server lists. You can take the server out of lan mode by changing the `sv_lan` setting in your `garrysmod/cfg/server.cfg` file.

```
sv_lan 0
```

Comment: I know this question is old but hopefully this helps someone like me googling years later